# Python how to ctrl c to terminate threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am developing a server in python and right now I need to be able to finish the server with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> while I am doing some testing.

Right now when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, the program doesn't end and I have the threads set at `daemon = True` as this, if I'm not wrong, enables me to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and finish the program even if the threads are still running. This doesn't work right now. Why?

```
thread_udp = threading.Thread(target=listen_udp)
thread_tcp = threading.Thread(target=listen_tcp)
thread_udp.daemon = True
thread_tcp.daemon = True
thread_udp.start()
thread_tcp.start()
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on the "doesn't work right now" part. What happens when you press `Ctrl-C`? What is supposed to happen? And how do you catch the `Ctrl-C` "signal"?

Comment: So, when I use ctrl-c I want it to end the program and the program right now doesn't end.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Then please try to create a [mcve] to show us, because with that little context you show us isn't enough for us to replicate or see your problem. All we can do is guess (badly!). Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I am on linux right now

Comment: Just tried simple script with python 3.6.8 on Win10. With `daemon=True` ctrl+C works (stops all threads) in windows command prompt and does not work (spawned threads continue to run) in python shell (idle).

Comment: well, I have exactly the code that I posted and it doesn't stop all threads and it keeps running. I am using a virtual ubuntu machine

Comment: This is not enough to reproduce the problem, please post a sufficiently large example that reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do to get this to work

Make your threads as `daemon`, daemonizing the threading would result in exiting all the threads when main thread exits.

You also would need to catch `ctr-c` signal which is `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in python and then do a simple `sys.exit(1)`.

With `python2` you might have some weird cases where it does not work as expected but if you are using `python3` it should work just fine.